# VB6 while formatting Currency in the TextBox , in place of '$' , it is displaying '?'

Tags: vb6

I have a textbox in which I want to display amount with `$` symbol. I have written the formatting line. But instead of `$` it is displaying `?`

```
     .txtField(priceAmt).Text = Format$(0, "currency")
```

If I have amount `55.00`, it is getting displayed as `? 55.00`. I want it to be displayed as `$55.00`.

This is happening in only my machine. When other person took the same code, it is giving expected result.

Comment: "Currency" is locale-aware.  Are you in a different locale?  Another option would be to try something like `Format$(0, "$0.00")`

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions :
1.As comment suggested by @Brian M Stafford, I changed line to Format$(0, "$0.00"). This worked for me.
2.In control panel settings, Currency was set to rupees symbol. I changed it into $ then it worked for me.

[image: Image of Currency Setting tab]

Comment: If you want a dollar sign in all cases and for all users, then you must use your option 1, because (as you saw) a user's Currency symbol may differ from what you expect.